# CSS/Javascript- Ignore readonly input to read in a form

Tags: javascript, forms, readonly

I'm just trying to **ignore** all 'readonly' Input values to read in the form. Below is the input element I'm trying to ignore-

```
<input name="ctl00$MainContent$appFormDynamic$ctl00$PersonalDetails_Section$PersonalDetailsSection_ContactDetailsForm$AddressSearchControl$ucEditAddress$fkPostalCity$Input" 
id ="ctl00_MainContent_appFormDynamic_ctl00_PersonalDetails_Section_PersonalDetailsSection_ContactDetailsForm_AddressSearchControl_ucEditAddress_fkPostalCity_Input" 
type="text" readonly="readonly" value="test"></input>
```

I've tried using the below but had not joy, any suggestions please?

```
if ( $('input').is('[readonly!="readonly"]') ) { 
            formValues = //this should get all input values except readonly input.
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following jQuery returns all input elements which do NOT have a `readonly` attribute:

```
$("input:not([readonly])")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($('input').prop("readonly")!="readonly")
{
...
}
```

use `prop` or `attr` to get attribute of elements.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use:

```
$('input').not('[readonly]')
```